# Centering in tabularx columns

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to do centering and text sizing in tabularx environment using the following definitions:

```
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X}
```

However, when I want to center "s" using the following command, I get an error:

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering}{{\hsize=.25\hsize}X}}
```

Any ideas what might work? Thanks.

Comment: Try `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.25\hsize}X}`

Comment: sorry doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Hmmmmm..., it works on my `tabularx` using `|bs|` specifier.

Comment: @Sumit please always include a complete small document that shows the error. "doesn't work for me" doesn't allow anyone to help you. Every question should have an example starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not supplied a document so this is untested but you have incorrect syntax here:

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering}{{\hsize=.25\hsize}X}}
```

`>` takes a single argument and `>` and its argument must immediately precede the column specification or another `>` clause. So you need

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.25\hsize}X}
```

or, if you prefer

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X}
```

Answer (score 1):

With package `ragged2e`:

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\Centering\hsize=.25\hsize}X}
```

which also allows hyphenation.